# How to escape & in Oracle text - CONTAINS?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c, contains, oracle-text

I'm trying to get results for AT&T in SQL developer. I tried a couple of escape methods. Nothing seems to work. Can someone correct if the queries are wrong?

```
SELECT  DISTINCT(id)
FROM    words
WHERE   CONTAINS(word, 'AT' || chr(38) || 'T',1) > 0

SET ESCAPE ON
SELECT  DISTINCT(id)
FROM    words
WHERE   CONTAINS(word, 'AT\&T',1) > 0

SELECT  DISTINCT(id)
FROM    words
WHERE   CONTAINS(word, 'AT&' || 'T',1) > 0

SELECT  DISTINCT(id)
FROM    words
WHERE   CONTAINS(word, '{AT&T}',1) > 0
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume that there is an Oracle Text index on the `word` column of the `words` table so that the `contains` operator makes sense?  How is that index defined?  Does its lexer interpret the `&` character as a token separator? Are you getting an error when running any of these queries?  Is `SQL Developer` seeing the `&` character as a substitution variable?  If so, you'd want to have run `set define off` in the session before running any of these queries.

Comment: Here is how the index was created. CREATE INDEX word_text_index ON words(word) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT;  I did try SET DEFINE OFF, no luck. All the above queries return 0 result.

Comment: Tested with all test cases,Only 2nd and last works both in sqlplus and sql developer with set define off.

Comment: @Suresh, With BASIC_LEXER?

Comment: It worked with regular index.I dropped basic_lexar index before running test cases.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14218/cqspcl.htm#i1006222

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried both AT\&T and {AT&T}. No luck. "and" is in default stoplist. Could it be because of that? If we remove "and" from the stopword list, do you think it would work? I'm guessing this because other stopwords aren't returning results as well.